# How to add selected attribute in option

Tags: php, jquery

I have two drop down menu which is bind together.
i want to add selected attribute in my code but its not working here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = { search_by_type: <?php echo $json_data; ?> };
$("#search_by_type").change(function () {
$('#category').empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Select category'));
var matchVal = $("#search_by_type option:selected").text();
data.search_by_type.filter(function (cat) {
if (cat.TE == matchVal) {
$("#category").append($('<option selected="selected"></option>').val(cat.CI).html(cat.CE)); // Here i set id in value field
}
});
});
$('#category').change(function () {
$('#size').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Here is my json data

```
[{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Boul\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "e723aadf-be9f-4f3e-b55f-4a80ac479441"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Dakni\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "bd38a507-18de-4897-90a1-1825d86a2d86"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Krishn Bhakti Shakha\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "bfca4966-7559-4652-b392-0df98b3dae3a"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Nath\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "12643016-5125-4cbd-a32f-dd67316dd451"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Niranjani\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "0e5c1165-c469-4d8e-83fb-2ec1bade1eb8"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Nirguni\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "092d2309-5f28-47d4-a577-6f279f2e4daf"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Others\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "19693ea9-dadb-4264-972f-32eddd21877e"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Ram Bhakti Shakha\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "3f772798-bdcf-44cf-b561-867f76c8e6d4"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sikh Gurus\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "b3001ff0-36ba-4055-92ff-828d658fa91b"
},
{
    "TI": "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342",
    "TE": "Saint",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Vaishnav\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "7dc9b7ef-5b4a-4499-a1b2-2049d65681c8"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Chishtiya",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "5e3b6942-413e-4c17-adeb-1f491f858a26"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Firdausiya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "2ca96833-1602-4ada-b6c3-af3acde35fe4"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Madariya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "c4a354b0-43e3-4caf-98f3-afb74a4c1001"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Naqsbandiya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "abdf23dd-8678-4103-b4ab-35c1b932a9f1"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Others",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "9abdf62c-f2fb-426f-bee0-ae48dc025ff1"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "ovasiya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "89fd86eb-7023-4c5d-90aa-b14b5efc3069"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Qadariya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "c06b1953-9a0a-431d-9908-393995145ea5"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Qalandariya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "a7910a03-14a1-4bf8-893c-88ffb97637f2"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "shattariya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "8f4a879a-7177-4089-9a33-1793eaab8aac"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sufis of Bihar\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "a80a58cb-c0f7-4a72-b686-cbded120fb1a"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sufis of Dakan\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "c925ccb1-7e0d-40ea-81f7-23fa54181e69"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sufis of Gujrat\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "a23e00ab-1929-4de3-956d-c03be68653ee"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sufis of Iran\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "70a17ed3-a117-4fcf-ba24-80401afe7169"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sufis of Kashmir\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "58589976-ee2e-48d5-b4f7-22ebbb614c3e"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sufis of Punjab\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "0d1dda6d-8def-4cce-91e3-29efe4000dd6"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Sufis of Sindh\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "ff16b2a7-9474-44a6-b1a8-56e814acee7c"
},
{
    "TI": "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718",
    "TE": "Sufi",
    "TH": "",
    "TU": "",
    "CE": "Suhrawardiya\r\n",
    "CH": "",
    "CU": "",
    "CI": "b98d0806-4455-47ba-99e3-7f3d8a607c5e"
}]
```

Here is my PHP Script

```
<select class="filter-btn" name="search_by_type" id="search_by_type">
<option value=""> -Search by type- </option>
<?php $typeId = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : false;
$selected = 'selected="selected"'; ?>
<option <?php if($typeId=="83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342"){ echo $selected; } ?> id="83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342" value="Saint">Saint</option>
<option <?php if($typeId=="6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718"){ echo $selected; } ?> id="6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718" value="Sufi">Sufi</option>
</select>
<select class="filter-btn" name="category" id="category">
<option value=""> -Select category- </option>
</select>
<span class="search-btn"> <button type="submit" name="subm" id="search"> Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button> </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call **change** function as well, when setting the value in **category** dropdown. Have a look at below snippet.

```
if (cat.TE == matchVal) {
$("#category").append($('<option selected="selected"></option>').val(cat.CI).html(cat.CE)); // Here i set id in value field
$("#category").change();
}
```

Below is the code based on your question, which I have used :

```
<form action="index.php?type=83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342" method="post">
    <select class="filter-btn" name="search_by_type" id="search_by_type">
    <option value=""> -Search by type- </option>
        <?php $typeId = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : false;
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        ?>
        <option <?php if ($typeId == "83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342") {
            echo $selected;
        } ?> id="83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342" value="Saint">Saint</option>
        <option <?php if ($typeId == "6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718") {
            echo $selected;
        } ?> id="6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718" value="Sufi">Sufi</option>
    </select>
    <select class="filter-btn" name="category" id="category">
        <option value=""> -Select category- </option>
    </select>

    <span class="search-btn"> <button type="submit" name="subm" id="search"> Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button> </span>
    </form>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">            
        var data = JSON.parse('{ "search_by_type":  [{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Boul\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"e723aadf-be9f-4f3e-b55f-4a80ac479441"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Dakni\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"bd38a507-18de-4897-90a1-1825d86a2d86"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Krishn Bhakti Shakha\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"bfca4966-7559-4652-b392-0df98b3dae3a"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Nath\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"12643016-5125-4cbd-a32f-dd67316dd451"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Niranjani\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"0e5c1165-c469-4d8e-83fb-2ec1bade1eb8"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Nirguni\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"092d2309-5f28-47d4-a577-6f279f2e4daf"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Others\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"19693ea9-dadb-4264-972f-32eddd21877e"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Ram Bhakti Shakha\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"3f772798-bdcf-44cf-b561-867f76c8e6d4"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sikh Gurus\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"b3001ff0-36ba-4055-92ff-828d658fa91b"},{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Vaishnav\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"7dc9b7ef-5b4a-4499-a1b2-2049d65681c8"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Chishtiya","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"5e3b6942-413e-4c17-adeb-1f491f858a26"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Firdausiya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"2ca96833-1602-4ada-b6c3-af3acde35fe4"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Madariya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"c4a354b0-43e3-4caf-98f3-afb74a4c1001"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Naqsbandiya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"abdf23dd-8678-4103-b4ab-35c1b932a9f1"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Others","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"9abdf62c-f2fb-426f-bee0-ae48dc025ff1"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"ovasiya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"89fd86eb-7023-4c5d-90aa-b14b5efc3069"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Qadariya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"c06b1953-9a0a-431d-9908-393995145ea5"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Qalandariya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"a7910a03-14a1-4bf8-893c-88ffb97637f2"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"shattariya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"8f4a879a-7177-4089-9a33-1793eaab8aac"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sufis of Bihar\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"a80a58cb-c0f7-4a72-b686-cbded120fb1a"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sufis of Dakan\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"c925ccb1-7e0d-40ea-81f7-23fa54181e69"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sufis of Gujrat\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"a23e00ab-1929-4de3-956d-c03be68653ee"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sufis of Iran\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"70a17ed3-a117-4fcf-ba24-80401afe7169"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sufis of Kashmir\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"58589976-ee2e-48d5-b4f7-22ebbb614c3e"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sufis of Punjab\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"0d1dda6d-8def-4cce-91e3-29efe4000dd6"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Sufis of Sindh\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"ff16b2a7-9474-44a6-b1a8-56e814acee7c"},{"TI":"6383c9a3-8813-493b-a4d8-d882e49c3718","TE":"Sufi","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Suhrawardiya\\r\\n","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"b98d0806-4455-47ba-99e3-7f3d8a607c5e"}] }');
        $("#search_by_type").change(function () {
        $('#category').empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Select category'));
        var matchVal = $("#search_by_type option:selected").text();
        data.search_by_type.filter(function (cat) {
        if (cat.TE == matchVal) {
        $("#category").append($('<option selected="selected"></option>').val(cat.CI).html(cat.CE)); // Here i set id in value field
                    }
                });
            });
        $('#category').change(function() {
            $('#size').val($(this).val());
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: i have already do this. i will explain my function. i have two drop down a category another is subcategory.I have also a filter button when i click on button than my page reloads that time i want to display selected subcategory in drop down.

Comment: Can you share JSON data, from which your category dropdown derives?

Comment: @Vivek, I meant the actual data that your PHP page is inducing in this block.

Comment: data is coming from an api. it is actual data i encode this  right now

Comment: @VivekMishra, your logic for setting option based on "type" parameter is correct for me, just make sure you get this parameter. Also you have to place your JS script at the bottom of page. Make sure you parse your json data before using it in script : var data = JSON.parse('{ "search_by_type": [{"TI":"83643aca-c07d-4431-9550-2a8479dd2342","TE":"Saint","TH":"","TU":"","CE":"Boul","CH":"","CU":"","CI":"e723aadf-be9f-4f3e-b55f-4a80ac479441"}] }'); . There was \r\n in JSON data, make sure you replace them with \\r\\n.